# ColdFusion report does not open CSV file in Excel

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a ColdFusion report (version 9) that opens to a `*.csv` file.  The file will render to the screen, it used to open Excel automatically.  The data is in a *.csv format.  If you right click on the page, do a save as *.csv, it will open in excel at that point.  It would be nice if it just opened in excel, like it used to do it.  Maybe this is some new security setting in the browser that blocks it from automatically opening?  I set the local work station extension to open Excel with a `*.csv` but that did not help.  Using Chrome & IE browsers.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a text editor? Is it in the correct format?

Comment: What do the `content-type` and `content-disposition` headers have for values?

Comment: <cfreport format="CSV" template="report/rpt.cfr" query="ReportData" >  This is the tag that I am using to render the report.  Do not see "content-type", "content-disposition" options.  The data that renders to the page is in a comma delimited format with a header, it is in a CSV format.  It can be cut/pasted into a text editor.  I prefer it open excel when it renders, it makes for a "clean" excel format.  Since I updated to CF10 it no longer renders a CSV format to excel.  Miss the good old days.

Comment: Spent some more time working with this, the CSV format does not open excel in any CF server version.  The issue maybe a browser setting?  IE & CHROME just render the CSV to the screen with-out opening excel.  You can copy the text from the screen to a text file and open it in excel, it works that way, not a viable solution for site users.